# Using the variable in TextEditingController in another dart file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

I am trying to use the variable name `_firstNameCtrlr` in another page or rather class file.
**File1.dart**

```
final _firstNameCtrlr = TextEditingController();
```

**File2.dart**

```
class TxtFrmFldCtrlr{
  static void clearField(){
    _firstNameCtrlr.clear();
  }
}
```

The reason why I am trying to separate this function is that so I could put them all in one file, however the I cannot access the variable name of TextEditingController.

I tried importing the **File1.dart** in **File2.dart** but it did not fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by passing the widgets controller in clearField function.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class TxtFrmFldCtrlr{
  static void clearField(TextEditingController _firstNameCtrlr){
    _firstNameCtrlr.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this one worked and just passed the parameter on the first page. it is now working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A variable with a name starting with an underscore (_) is private to its library. You can only access it in the file where it is defined.

Name the variable firstNameCtrlr, without underscore, and import the file where it is defined into the file where you want to use it.